# Imported certification from nexus but still getting PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException

Tags: eclipse, maven, nexus

I'm trying to deploy my project to the Nexus repository. I used the following command to import the certificate from Nexus using the keytool:

```
keytool -import -alias mycert -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.9\lib\security\cacerts" -file nexusrepo-dev
```

After that I followed the instructions in this article to add the necessary plugins: Deploying Java Artifacts on a Nexus Repository with Maven.

```
https://rodolfombc.medium.com/deploying-java-artifacts-on-a-nexus-repository-with-maven-939a80406acf
```

I then rebuilt my project (run as -> maven install), but when deploying it using the following steps: Run As -> Run Configurations -> Deploy, I encountered the following error message:

```
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: You are running from your IDE or from plain command line? Have you restarted your IDE and are you sure you are using the same JDK ?

Comment: The keytool command was on my CMD, IDE was already restarted multiple times, and yeah I'm using the same JDK (jdk-17.0.9)

Comment: Have you executed the `deploy` on plain command line?  Is the used JDK the same as JAVA_HOME tells... ? Does the file used with keytool the right format? What kind of pem, crt etc.?

Comment: No, I have not ("I'm in the process of doing so"), JAVA_HOME is also the same as the JDK, 
and the file used in keytool is of type .pem ("it's of right format").

Comment: I can't even mvn install on command line, it's returning issues related to dependencies (e.g. Failed to collect dependencies at com.github.appreciated:card:jar:2.0.0.beta4). 

I tried changing the version of this package and it did not work / removed it completly and it returned the same error for another package.

Comment: In the Maven run configuration you can specify which JRE/JDK should be used which might differ from the JRE used to run Eclipse. A Maven run configuration will not be run in the same Java VM process than the IDE, so restarting the IDE is not needed. Please show which JDK you have configure in your Maven run configuration.